# Go map lookup returns copy of the element?

Tags: go

It seems like Go's map lookup returns a copy of the element. Can't seem to find this described in the language spec. I wrote a [program](https://play.golang.org/p/jjlLo6WGUv) as below:

type T struct { n int }

```
m := make(map[string]T)
t := T{123}
m["123"] = t
t0 := m["123"]
t1 := m["123"]
t0.n = 456
t1.n = 789
fmt.Println(t, t0, t1)
```

I got the output as: {123} {456} {789}. Looks like every time a copy of the element is returned?

Comment: Are you asking where in the spec this behavior is required or what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm asking if this behavior is specified in the spec or not. Because this has implication to the program. I would know that lots of memory allocation/de-allocation will be done if I do frequent map lookup of big value objects

Comment: Ok. My question is explained by Not_a_Golfer. "Go does not pass references, ever'.

Answer (score 8):

Go does not pass references, ever. It either passes values, making copies on assignment, or these values can be pointers, in which case the copy is of a pointer, which is practically a reference.

So let's say we have

```
type Foo struct {
   Bar string
}
```

if we make a map of values, i.e.

```
m := map[string]Foo{}
```

then map accesses return a copy of a Foo, or a zero valued Foo:

```
m["x"] = Foo{"hello"}

y := m["x"]
```

`y` is now a different object than what's in the map, so changing its `Bar` won't affect the object in the map.

But, if we make the map a map of pointers:

```
m := map[string]*Foo{}
```

and then access it:

```
m["x"] = &Foo{"bar"}
y := m["x"]
```

y is now a pointer to the same object as in the map. We can change its `Bar` and it will affect the map:

```
y.Bar = "wat"
fmt.Println(m["x"].Bar)

// Will print "wat"
```

[Playground example.](https://play.golang.org/p/MAoa2ALEjY)